# Add thousands separator to column in dataframe in julia

Tags: formatting, julia, julia-dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns a and b and at the moment both are looking like column a, but I want to add separators so that column b looks like below. I have tried using the package format.jl. But I haven't gotten the result I'm afte. Maybe worth mentioning is that both columns is Int64 and the column names a and b is of type symbol.

```
 a      |    b
150000  | 1500,00 
27      | 27,00
16614   | 166,14
```

Is there some other way to solve this than using format.jl? Or is format.jl the way to go?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the commas in their typical positions rather than how you wrote them, this is one way:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Format

julia> f(x) = format(x, commas=true)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> df = DataFrame(a = [1000000, 200000, 30000])
3×1 DataFrame
 Row │ a       
     │ Int64
─────┼─────────
   1 │ 1000000
   2 │  200000
   3 │   30000

julia> transform(df, :a => ByRow(f) => :a_string)
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a        a_string  
     │ Int64    String
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ 1000000  1,000,000
   2 │  200000  200,000
   3 │   30000  30,000
```

If you instead want the row replaced, use `transform(df, :a => ByRow(f), renamecols=false)`.
If you just want the output vector rather than changing the DataFrame, you can use `format.(df.a, commas=true)`

You could write your own function `f` to achieve the same behavior, but you might as well use [the one someone already wrote inside the Format.jl package](https://github.com/JuliaString/Format.jl#flexible-format-function).

However, once you transform you data to `String`s as above, you won't be able to filter/sort/analyze the numerical data in the DataFrame. I would suggest that you apply the formatting in the printing step (rather than modifying the DataFrame itself to contain strings) by using the [PrettyTables](https://ronisbr.github.io/PrettyTables.jl/dev/man/formatters/) package. This can format the entire DataFrame at once.

```
julia> using DataFrames, PrettyTables

julia> df = DataFrame(a = [1000000, 200000, 30000], b = [500, 6000, 70000])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a        b     
     │ Int64    Int64 
─────┼────────────────
   1 │ 1000000    500
   2 │  200000   6000
   3 │   30000  70000

julia> pretty_table(df, formatters = ft_printf("%'d"))
┌───────────┬────────┐
│         a │      b │
│     Int64 │  Int64 │
├───────────┼────────┤
│ 1,000,000 │    500 │
│   200,000 │  6,000 │
│    30,000 │ 70,000 │
└───────────┴────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

*(Edited to reflect the updated specs in the question)*

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a = [150000, 27, 16614]);

julia> function insertdecimalcomma(n)
         if n < 100
           return string(n) * ",00"
         else
           return replace(string(n), r"(..)$" => s",\1")
         end
       end
insertdecimalcomma (generic function with 1 method)

julia> df.b = insertdecimalcomma.(df.a)

julia> df
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b       
     │ Int64   String  
─────┼─────────────────
   1 │ 150000  1500,00
   2 │     27  27,00
   3 │  16614  166,14
```

---

Note that the `b` column will necessarily be a `String` after this change, as integer types cannot store formatting information in them.

If you have a lot of data and find that you need better performance, you may also want to use the `InlineStrings` package:

```
julia> #same as before upto the function definition

julia> using InlineStrings

julia> df.b = inlinestrings(insertdecimalcomma.(df.a))
3-element Vector{String7}:
 "1500,00"
 "27,00"
 "166,14"
```

This stores the `b` column's data as fixed-size strings (`String7` type here), which are generally treated like normal `String`s, but can be significantly better for performance.

Comment: It's not really a typo. 1000000 should translate to 10 000,00. So that's ten thousand with two decimals at the end. 200000 should two thousands and 30000 should be three hundred. Now I live in Sweden so maybe it's a bit different how you separate numbers.

Comment: That makes sense. So the decimal point should be a comma, and the thousands separator should be just a space? The `10 000,00` seems to imply that, but the question has `1,0000,00`; that part at least seems to be a typo. Could you update the question with how exactly you want the numbers to look i.e. is it `10 000,00`, `2 000,00` and `300,00`?

Comment: I have updated the question. My first example maybe wasn't that clear, hope this is better. I really just want two decimal, and maybe I mixed that up with thousands separator.

Comment: I've updated the answer to match the updated examples.

Comment: I get a strange result. It looks like all numbers falls under ```if n < 100``` because 150000 becomes 150000,00.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using, at the end of the question perhaps? The output in my answer is all directly from the REPL, so it works as shown; either the code or the data must be different in some way on your end.

Answer (score 0):

May be someone will search here for a space thousand separator I cooked up the following regex based transcription :

```
#first conversion of a float to string (w/o scientific notation)
str = @sprintf("%.2f",nbr) 
matches = eachmatch(r"\d{1,3}(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))", str)
decimal_match = match(r"\d{3}\.\d+$", str)
... vcat the vector of matches with decimal part, then join with " "...
```

You only need to deal with numbers up < 100.00 as the regex doesn't account for them (it's simplistic but do the job). I use this function as a formatter in a pretty print of a DataFrame.